# How to merge row of selected column like excel sheet in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to implement similar functionality(merging rows and highlight it by color) of microsoft excel sheet. is there any methods, api or any sample code for such type of functionality.

Comment: implement similar functionality to where?

Comment: am trying to implement scheduler using NSTableView to display data. if you have any idea please let me know.

Comment: You have to use view based table view with custom drawing for row. As merging like row-span and col-span are not given in api.